# How to customize postnotes in biblatex in such a way it adds page number after each label?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

When I try to use `prenote` and `postnote` options with `\cite` command for multiple citations I get the following

[image]

However, I want to get the following result

> [see Ker18, p. 11; KÇC20, p. 11; TW15, p.1961]

Another variant I would love to get is

> [see Ker18; KÇC20; TW15; p. 11, 11, 1961]

Also, it seems that `multipostnotedelim` does not change to semicolon by the command `\renewcommand*{\multipostnotedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}`

My MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@book{kerr2018introduction,
    title={Introduction to Energy and Climate - Developing a Sustainable Environment},
    author={Julie Kerr},
    edition={1},
    year={2018},
    publisher={CRC Press}
}
@book{kanoğlu2010fundamentals,
    title={Fundamentals and Applications of Renewable Energy},
    author={Kanoğlu, Mehmet and Çengel, Yunus and Cimbala, John},
    edition={1},
    year={2020},
    publisher={McGraw Hill}
}
@book{twidell2015renewable,
    title={Renewable Energy Resources},
    author={Twidell, John and Weir, Tony},
    edition={3},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Routledge}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

%\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\multipostnotedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\begin{document}
    
    \cite[see][11, 11, 1961]{kerr2018introduction,kanoğlu2010fundamentals,twidell2015renewable}
    
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, `biblatex` has "qualified citation lists", which are variants of the regular citation commands with an "s", and which receive multiple citation keys, with individual pre/postnotes and a global pre/postnote (in parentheses). So for the two cases you asked, you can use:

```latex
\cites(see)()[11]{kerr2018introduction}[11]{kanoğlu2010fundamentals}[1961]{twidell2015renewable}

\cites(see)(11, 11, 1961){kerr2018introduction}{kanoğlu2010fundamentals}{twidell2015renewable}
```

In full:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{kerr2018introduction,
    title={Introduction to Energy and Climate - Developing a Sustainable Environment},
    author={Julie Kerr},
    edition={1},
    year={2018},
    publisher={CRC Press}
}
@book{kanoğlu2010fundamentals,
    title={Fundamentals and Applications of Renewable Energy},
    author={Kanoğlu, Mehmet and Çengel, Yunus and Cimbala, John},
    edition={1},
    year={2020},
    publisher={McGraw Hill}
}
@book{twidell2015renewable,
    title={Renewable Energy Resources},
    author={Twidell, John and Weir, Tony},
    edition={3},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Routledge}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cites(see)()[11]{kerr2018introduction}[11]{kanoğlu2010fundamentals}[1961]{twidell2015renewable}

\cites(see)(11, 11, 1961){kerr2018introduction}{kanoğlu2010fundamentals}{twidell2015renewable}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good. Is it possible to change pp. to p.?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh It certainly is, but that would be a different question altogether.